# Maven dependency only for testing purposes

Tags: java, maven, testing, spring-data-jpa

I have a maven dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And the thing is that the ${version} property should be replaced by 1.8.1.RELEASE or 1.9.0.RELEASE depending on the profile I choose when installing, but for testing purposes only the 1.9.0.RELEASE should be used, even if I'm using the 1.8.1 profile. Is there a way to do this? I tried using the test scope but it didn't work as I think it would.

Comment: Maybe something like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/177316/61537

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you?

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>defaultProfile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <magicVersion>1.9.0.RELEASE</magicVersion>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>Release181</id>
        <properties>
            <magicVersion>1.8.1.RELEASE</magicVersion>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <properties>
            <magicVersion>1.9.0.RELEASE</magicVersion>
        </properties>
    </profile>      
</profiles>
```

The idea being is activating the test profile will overwrite the version even if it's been set already by your 1.8.1 profile. Use case would be;

```
mvn -P Release181,test test
```